# github add <<<<<<< HEAD

Tags: git, github

hi i'm fairly new to github, when i made some changes to the code and then merge to upstream, if there are any conflicts,it will do the following.

```
Auto-merging Global.asax.cs CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in Global.asax.cs

<<<< HEAD
======
>>>> UPSTREA/MASTER
```

into my code. does anyone know why? and how to get rid of them?
Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a merge conflict between your remote and local. The less than and commit name (`HEAD` in your example) are inserted by Git.

There are a few useful tools to help resolve conflicts. The one I use, built into JetBrains IDEA, shows local changes on the LHS, remote changes on the RHS and the merge result in the middle. It works well for me, so try and find a tool that does the same if you're not comfortable using Git's `diff` tool.

Fix the conflicts, then `add`, `commit` and `push`.